# How do you go about initializing all the objects by the constructor?

Tags: c++, oop, constructor, initialization

How do you go about initializing all the objects by the constructor?

Suppose you have 4 Set objects inside a Location class.
How do you initialize the 4 set objects from the constructor to set as default? I tried to first create the objects already initialized :

Set nyX (nyXv); 
And then try to put it inside the constructor, but that will not work.

```
class Location
{
public:
    vector<int> nyXv = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    vector<int> nyYv = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    vector<int> sfXv = { 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
    vector<int> sfYv = { 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };


    Set nyX;
    Set nyY;

    Set sfX;
    Set sfY;


    Location();
    ~Location();

};



class Set
{
public:
    Set(vector<int> &);
};
```

Comment: Are you asking for the member initializer list?

Comment: Provide a default constructor that initializes them in the absence of data, then in the one that takes the vector, handle that accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You should use an [initialization list](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/initialization-lists-c++.html):

```
Location::Location()
  : nyX(nyXv)
{}
```